# SendMail use .NetCore with Linux-Docker

Tags: c#, .net, linux, docker, asp.net-core

When I run my .NET Core 6 API project locally or inside a Linux Docker container on my local machine, I am able to send emails without any issues. However, when I deploy it to my remote Ubuntu server using Docker, I am unable to send emails, and no error messages are shown.Help me please. I'm use mailkit..

```
  public async Task SendMailAsync(string email, string body, string subject, Dictionary<string, byte[]> attachments)
        {
            string smtpHost = _appSettings.Value.MailHost; // mail.kurumsaleposta.com
            int smtpPort = _appSettings.Value.MailPort; // 587
            string smtpUsername = _appSettings.Value.MailUsername;
            string smtpPassword = _appSettings.Value.MailPassword;
            string displayName = _appSettings.Value.MailDisplayName;
            bool enableSsl = true;
            try
            {
                var message = new MimeMessage();
                message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(displayName, smtpUsername));
                message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", email)); 

                message.Subject = subject;

                var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
                string bodysablon = File.ReadAllText("MailTemplate/MailTemplate.html");

                var sablon = bodysablon.Replace("[MailTemplate]", body);

                bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = sablon;
                bodyBuilder.TextBody = "";

                message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

                if (attachments != null && attachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var attachment in attachments)
                    {
                        Stream stream = new MemoryStream(attachment.Value);
                        bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, attachment.Key).ToString());
                    }
                }

                using (MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient clients = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
                {
                    clients.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
              
                    await clients.ConnectAsync(smtpHost, smtpPort,false);
                    await clients.AuthenticateAsync(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
                    await clients.SendAsync(message);
                    await clients.DisconnectAsync(true);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("err", ex);

            }
```

I tried changing the port, and since my domain has an SSL certificate, I also tried setting ssl to true, but it still didn't work.

Comment: You never log any errors. Add code to actually log the errors. `throw new Exception("err", ex);` is meaningless and actually harmful because it modifies the stack trace of the actual exception. If you don't intend to handle or log the exception, don't catch it. To rethrow use `throw;` alone

Comment: Does the issue has been fixed ? If it is fixed, could you share more details about the issue, it could help more users who will face the same issue in the future.

Comment: @JasonPan Hi.
When I start it up with Docker Compose, I can't send emails, but
When I start it with the commands

 `docker build -t testapi .
docker run -d --name test-api -p 8084:80 testapi`

I can send emails. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to expose mulitiple ports for your application. I mean the port 587.

If it not work, please try `globalSettings__mail__smtp__trustServer=true`. For more details, please check [this github issue](https://github.com/bitwarden/server/issues/457).

Comment: where do i write that code

Comment: Hi @OguzDemirel,  we should find env configuration file, you need share more details.